# Kindle version of Crystal's Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics, 7th ed. -- usable?

Tags: dictionary

Is the Kindle version of Crystal's Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics usable? For example, do special symbols, tables and graphics display properly? How is the search feature?

I've owned hard-bound versions of previous editions, but now I'm tempted to buy the Kindle version of the 7th edition. Some Kindle products don't display non-text content very well.

Thanks.

Comment: I glanced at the free Amazon sample of the Kindle version and did not find any errors of rendering, though it is 95% ordinary-text. It has the expected errors and infelicities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I also checked out the free sample and found that it was OK. But I was hoping someone might own the entire book on Kindle and be able to tell me if they've found it frustrating to use.